# JSON error. Unexpected character

Tags: jquery, json

My server is returning the following json object:

```
{"Success":0,"ex":"The system cannot find the file specified"}
```

When I run `var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data)` I get the following error:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: data is already an object, you dont need to apply parseJSON on it again.

Comment: yes, for it works for string: http://jsfiddle.net/WX5yN/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseJSON` is used to parse a **JSON string** into a **Javascript object**. Looks like you already have the object, are you sure `data` is a string?

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem.